# modelformset_factory: unknown column '<model>.id' in field list (intermediary table)

Tags: django, model, formsets

I'm trying to create a formset model from an intermediary table that I created to manage a manytomany table using Django 1.7 and Python3.2.

This is my intermediary model and note that 'managed' is set to 'False'.

```
# models.py
class Intermediary(models.Model):
   sid = models.ForeignKey(Sellers, db_column='sid')
   cid = models.ForeignKey(Competitors, db_column='cid')
   date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'intermediary'
```

Python shell:

```
>>> from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
>>> from myapp.models import Intermediary
>>> IntermediaryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Intermediary)
>>> formset = IntermediaryFormSet()
>>> print(formset)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
    blablity-blah-blah
    blablity-blah-blah
    ...
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Unknown column 'intermediary.id' in 'field list'.
```

But as you can see there's no 'id' column in my model. I think this ghost column is an implicit one created by Django's magic.

I am also getting the same error filtering by another column:

```
IntermediaryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Intermediary, fields=('sid',))
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a primary key to both the model and sql table solved my problem.